# how to create chat room using smack API in java programatically

Tags: java, smack

I'm trying to create a Chatroom using SMACK API for java programmatically for a Java Application. It doesn't show any error but no rooms are getting created.

Following is the code :

```
MultiUserChat oMultiUserChat = new MultiUserChat(connection,"test_open_house@example.com");
        try {
            oMultiUserChat.create("test_open_house");
              oMultiUserChat.sendRegistrationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
            oMultiUserChat.join("example");
                    } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Using this The chat room isn't getting created.
Connection is established succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

```
MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(Connection, roomName +"@conference." + Domain);    
         muc.create("UserNickName");
         muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
```

dont forget to include the service name e.g conference in this case 
What server are you using? if you are using openfire the service name must me conference. and it should be like this:
test_open_house@.conferece.example.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i have changed technology to design MultiUser chat room. Now i am designing it in Node.js